# Welch Test Statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, conditional-expectation, moment-generating-function

I've read journal article *On the Comparison of Several Mean Values: An Alternative Approach* [(Welch, 1951)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2332579). How can I derive the MGF of the Welch statistic? Are there other methods to get the Welch test statistic aside from the method in that journal?

The expression for the MGF given on page 331 (eq. (5)) of the paper

$$
\begin{align}
M(u) &= \mathbb{E}\exp  (u(\sum_t w_t(y_t - \hat{y})^2)) \\    
&= (1-2u)^{-1/2(k-1)}(1+(2u(1-2u)^{-1} \\
&\quad +3u^2(1-2u)^{-2}( \sum_t 1/{f_t} (1-(\omega_t/ \sum_t \omega_t))^2))
\end{align}
$$
where the second expression is given on page 333 of the paper (eq. (18)).

[Link to ungated copy of the paper](http://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=on%20the%20comparison%20of%20several%20mean%20values&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://www.soph.uab.edu/Statgenetics/People/MBeasley/Courses/Welch1951.pdf&ei=Q4O4UKrvHIfkrAeBkIDABg&usg=AFQjCNE9v2uBUWrJl5dtliD-qJ_mpuT81A).